# Who are these alternate-dimension Batmen?

Tags: dc, batman, character-identification, the-brave-and-the-bold

From *Batman: The Brave and the Bold*:

[image: Alternate dimension Batmen]

These are various Batmen from different dimensions. Regular Batman is in the middle.

I recognize Vampire Batman and Captain Leatherwing but I need help with the others.

Comment: You might enjoy this pic; http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/braveandbold/images/6/6c/Tumblr_inline_mr28djElPU1qz4rgp.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140213085152

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The various Batmen are described on the [Brave and the Bold Wikia](http://braveandbold.wikia.com/wiki/Batmen_of_the_Multiverse)

The ones in that picture appear to be (from left to right):

- **Rough-Rider Batman:** inspired by the [Justice Riders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_Riders) comics
- **Bat-Hulk**: from the pages of [Brave and the Bold #68](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Brave_and_the_Bold_Vol_1_68), 1966
- **Bat Vampire**: from the Elseworlds comic [Batman & Dracula: Red Rain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_%26_Dracula_trilogy), 1991
- **Plain old Batman** (A creation of Brave and the Bold)
- **[Solar Batman](http://braveandbold.wikia.com/wiki/Solar_Batman)** (A creation of Brave and the Bold)
- **Captain Leatherwing**: from the Elseworlds story in [Detective Comics Annual #7](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Detective_Comics_Annual_Vol_1_7), 1994
- **[Batman of 800,000AD](http://braveandbold.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_of_800,000_A.D.)** (A creation of Brave and the Bold)

Comment: I'm guessing you're going to put them in order, so I shouldn't do it for you?

Comment: @WadCheber - /Sigh. Happy now?

Comment: I was actually being serious.  I was going to do it for you, but I figured you'd do it and my edit would be preempted.  Happy to see you posting, btw.